# ServiceStack Deserializing

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I'm able to get ServiceStack to serialize my objects but deserializing is another story.  I'm receiving this json:

```
{
   "Return": {
       "A":15,
       "B":16,
       "Result":240
   },
   "Time":0.0743458271027
}
```

And I want to deserialize it to this class type:

```
public class Result<T>
{
    public T Return;
    public double Time;
}
```

which T in this case is Math:

```
public class Math
{
    public int A;
    public int B;
    public int C;
    public decimal Result;
}
```

I've used Newtonsoft.Json and all is well, but ServiceStack should be 3 times faster but I just get objects with no values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [ServiceStack text serializers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) doesn't serialize public fields, but you can enable them with:

```
JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;
```